# cgroups: how to detach a process from cgroup

Tags: cgroups

I have created a cgroup `mygroup` in my system and running a process under it

```
cgexec -g memory,cpu:groupname/mygroup someprocess
```

Now after some time when i feel there is no need to worry about the cpu and memory, how to detach the process from cgroup which i have applied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a [*cgroup*](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/cgroups.7) subsystem is made available (by mounting it), a process is always part of a *cgroup* within this subsystem's hierarchy, and that will initially be its root *cgroup*, unless moved in an other *cgroup*, where its descendents will appear too. "Detaching" a process usually means moving it (back) to the root *cgroup* of the given subsystem(s).

Assuming subsystems are already adequately mounted, everything is available by creating/removing pseudo-directories or reading/writing adequate values to pseudo-files appearing in those directories usually under `/sys/fs/cgroup` as described in [`man cgroups.7`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/cgroups.7), else the dedicated command provided along `cgexec` is [`cgclassify`](https://manpages.debian.org/cgroup-tools/cgclassify.1).

Here's an example (using *cgroups* v1) to illustrate it from a bash shell:

```
# ls /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/groupname/mygroup
ls: cannot access '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/groupname/mygroup': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/groupname/mygroup': No such file or directory

# cgcreate -g memory,cpu:groupname/mygroup

# ls -d /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/groupname/mygroup
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/groupname/mygroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/groupname/mygroup
```

Of course some dedicated settings could probably be applied after creating the cgroups above.

```
# cgexec -g memory,cpu:groupname/mygroup sh -c 'echo $$; exec sleep 999'
14682
```

Other terminal:

```
# grep -w 14682 /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/groupname/mygroup/cgroup.procs 
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/groupname/mygroup/cgroup.procs:14682
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/groupname/mygroup/cgroup.procs:14682
# grep -w 14682 /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/cgroup.procs
#

# cgclassify -g memory,cpu:/ 14682

# grep -w 14682 /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/groupname/mygroup/cgroup.procs
# grep -w 14682 /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/cgroup.procs:14682
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cgroup.procs:14682
```

The three dedicated commands above could have been replaced by these simple shell commands:

```
# mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/groupname/mygroup
# bash -c 'echo $$ | tee /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/groupname/mygroup/cgroup.procs; exec sleep 999'
15533
```

and (to "detach" it):

```
# echo 15533 | tee /sys/fs/cgroup/{memory,cpu}/cgroup.procs
15533
```

Note actually the dedicated command `cgclassify`, at least on *cgroups* v1 acts on the process' threads (using `.../tasks`) rather than the process itself (using `.../cgroup.procs`). For simple processes, the pid (process ID) which is the unique thread and thus the task group ID (tgid=pid), is seen the same in both pseudo-files and there is no difference. For multi-threaded processes, moving the whole process requires to identify all of its threads when using `.../tasks` or simply to use `.../cgroup.procs`. It's in the man:

> When writing a PID into the `cgroup.procs`, all threads in the process
> are moved into the new cgroup at once.

> In cgroups v1, an individual thread can be moved to another cgroup by
> writing its thread ID (i.e., the kernel thread ID returned by clone(2)
> and gettid(2)) to the `tasks` file in a cgroup directory. This file can
> be read to discover the set of threads that are members of the cgroup.

That's why I chose to display and use `.../cgroup.procs` after. It would matter when moving a multithreaded process like Firefox, a java application, etc. `pgrep --lightweight` could be used to provide all the tasks to `cgclassify` for this case (beware of races though).